# How to obtain a floating point approximiation of an expression resulting from sympy functions

Tags: sympy

From several sympy operations I obtain the following expression:

```
7 + 5*(0.333333333333333 + 2.77555756156289e-17*I)*(16.4290313669059 - 
2.58254419061622e-14*I)**(1/3) + 1.66666666666667*(-205.429031366906 + 
1.12467926387254e-13*I)**(1/3) + ((0.333333333333333 + 2.77555756156289e- 
17*I)*(16.4290313669059 - 2.58254419061622e-14*I)**(1/3) + 0.333333333333333* 
(-205.429031366906 + 1.12467926387254e-13*I)**(1/3))**3
```

I would like to obtain an approximate floating point value (it should be very near to 0). I tried the following (assigning the value to "r"):

```
eval("%s"%r)
```

but this only gives me the result:

```
(0.333333333333333 + 2.77555756156289e-17*I)*(16.4290313669059 - 
2.58254419061622e-14*I)**0.333333333333333 + 0.333333333333333* 
(-205.429031366906 + 1.12467926387254e-13*I)**0.333333333333333
```

close, but no cigar.

Comment: If the expression is `e` then you can use `e.evalf()` for this.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin this solves the problem perfecly, thanks